# basis of the lattice generated by the integer points inside a subspace of R^L

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, lattices, diophantine-equations, integer-programming

Consider $K$ linearly independent vectors $\mathbf{a}_1, \mathbf{a}_2, ..., \mathbf{a}_K \in \mathbb{Z}^L$, where $1 \leq K<L $. Hence, the span of $\lbrace\mathbf{a}_1, \mathbf{a}_2, ..., \mathbf{a}_K\rbrace$ on real numbers is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^L $ with dim $K$. Denote this subspace as $V=Span\lbrace\mathbf{a}_1, \mathbf{a}_2, ..., \mathbf{a}_K\rbrace$.

I think the integer points inside this span, i.e. $V \bigcap \mathbb{Z}^L$ , form a lattice of rank $K$ in $\mathbb{Z}^L$ (is it true?). What is the basis (generator matrix) of this lattice? How it can be computed explicitly from $\mathbf{a}_1, \mathbf{a}_2, ..., \mathbf{a}_K $?

In brief, given the linearly independent vectors $\mathbf{a}_1, \mathbf{a}_2, ..., \mathbf{a}_K \in \mathbb{Z}^L$, I want the basis for the lattice:
$$ \Lambda =\lbrace \mathbf{b}\in {\mathbb{Z}^L} \vert \mathbf{b}=\sum\limits_{k = 1}^K {{\alpha _k}{{\mathbf{a}}_k}}  ,\,{\alpha _1}, \cdots ,{\alpha _K} \in \mathbb{R}  \rbrace$$
(what if $\mathbf{a}_1, \mathbf{a}_2, ..., \mathbf{a}_K \in \mathbb{R}^L$ ?)

Comment: You don't generally get a lattice of dim K. (A line of irrational slope in R^2 won't hit any nontrivial integer points.)

Comment: You right for the case that vectors a_1,...,a_K are in R^n (last line of my question!). but for the case that a_1,...,a_K are in Z^L, at least these integer points and their integer combinations are in the span V and may form a lattice.

Answer (score 2):

Although the brute force [solution of Alex](https://mathoverflow.net/a/192041/149270) is certainly possible, it is not very efficient.
It would be easier in practice to use [Hermite's normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_normal_form):

First, find a linear map $A \in \mathbb{Z}^{(L-K) \times L}$, such that $V = \ker(A)$ is the null space of $A$ (which can be found by computing the null space of the matrix with $V$ as its rowspace).

Next, compute the Hermite normal form of $A$ to obtain a decomposition
$H = AU$,
where $H \in \mathbb{Z}^{(L-K) \times L}$ is in column-style Hermite normal form, and $U \in \mathbb{Z}^{L\times L}$ is a unimodular matrix (that is, $U : \mathbb{Z}^L \to \mathbb{Z}^L$ is an isomorphism).

For $\Lambda_H = \ker(H) \cap \mathbb{Z}^n$, we have
\begin{align*}
\Lambda &= \ker(A) \cap \mathbb{Z}^n \\
&= \{\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{Z}^n \mid A\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{0} \} \\
&= \{\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{Z}^n \mid HU^{-1}\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{0} \} \\
&= \{U\mathbf{y} \mid \mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{Z}^n, H\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{0} \} \\
&= U\Lambda_H
\end{align*}
As $H$ is in column-style Hermite normal form, it is straightforward to find a basis for the lattice $\Lambda_H$ (it is a subset of the standard basis). Application of the isomorphism $U$ yields a basis for the lattice $\Lambda$.

Comment: Isn't it always a subset of the standard basis? Just checking I'm not missing something.

Comment: You are right. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Disregarding the last line of your question, yes, you do get a lattice of rank $K$, and this lattice can be computed explicitly. A quick and dirty algorithm would use

> MR0525944 (80j:10031) Reviewed
>   Nikulin, V. V.
>   Integer symmetric bilinear forms and some of their geometric applications. (Russian)
>   Izv. Akad. Nauk SSSR Ser. Mat. 43 (1979), no. 1, 111–177, 238.

The thing is that the lattice in question is a finite index extension of the original lattice, say, $S$. Restricting to $S$ the Euclidean inner product, we make it a true nondegenerate lattice, and then it has but finitely many finite index extensions: they are enumerated by the isotropic subgroups of the finite group $\operatorname{discr}S$. Each has an explicit basis (made by rational vectors in the basis of $S$), and one can try them all one by one to see if these vectors are actually integral.

Comment: Do you mean a lattice of rank $K$?

As an example, consider the case $L=3$, $K=2$:

$\mathbf{a}_1=[2,0,0], \mathbf{a}_2=[0,2,0]$, then a basis for the lattice $\Lambda$ is:

$\mathbf{e}_1=[1,0,0], \mathbf{e}_2=[0,1,0]$

and the lattice rank is 2.

Comment: And also the reference you introduced is too complex for me to understand! Any simpler solution? thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's $K$ of course.

Comment: I don't see why it's complicated. In any case, if time doesn't matter, it suffices to try linear combinations of $\mathbf{a}_i$ with denominators $n$ such that $n^2$ divides the determinant of the Gram matrix. There are finitely many such vectors (modulo the original lattice).